# Module 'ionic.service.analytics' is not available

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, analytics

I'm getting the following error when injecting `$ionicAnalytics`

[image]

The **ionic-platform-web-client** has been installed correctly:

[image]

It's also **referenced** correctly:

```
<script src="lib/ionic-platform-web-client/dist/ionic.io.bundle.js"></script>
```

I'm also using the correct **CLI version**:

[image]

I've created a very simple sample project [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au51a7A33VMah7IBq-2M3BL0A_3d6w)

**Does anybody have an idea what could be wrong?**

> NOTE: We have this issue only on **iOS**, it does work on Android.

Comment: Could you solve the error?

Comment: We haven't solved the issue yet, we decided not to use the service in the meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. `ionic io init` solved it.